# Updating a Particular Value in Multimap

Tags: java, hashmap, multimap

I want to implement HashMap – Single Key and Multiple Values using Google Guava Collections. 
In which i am able to store Multiple values for a Single Key. But i am finding it difficult to update particular (Value) associated with a key keeping other Values intact.
For e.g. 
under key 1 , i have values A,B,C,D . 
Key = 1
Values = [A, B, C, D]

```
multiMap.put(1,"A");
multiMap.put(1,"B");
multiMap.put(1,"C");
multiMap.put(1,"D");
```

If i want to update the Value "B" to "X" -- Please help me understand how it can be implemented.

Comment: Did you get answer for this //

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to do it the long way.

```
multiMap.get(Integer.valueOf(1 /* or whatever your key is */)).remove("B");
multiMap.get(Integer.valueOf(1)).add("X");
```

Or retrieve all the entries, loop through them until you find the one with the key and value you want and replace the value.